# PHP output newline in a single character using bitwise NOT operator

Tags: php, operators

I have found in different web sites (for example [here](https://dsolstad.com/phpgolf/2018/05/01/phpGolf-tips-and-tricks.html)) this statement:

This PHP code prints a newline using 10 bytes:

```
echo "\n";
```

This PHP code prints a newline using 9 bytes:

```
echo "
";
```

This PHP code prints a newline using 8 bytes (using the [bitwise NOT operator ~](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785054/bit-not-operation-in-phpor-any-other-language-probably)):

```
echo ~õ;
```

My problem is that I can't make that last solution work in any possible way, test and environment that I used. I have tested on online PHP sandboxes, on local machine, etc, when I execute

```
echo ~õ;
```

I get always this output:

```
<J
```

Why? Can someone explain why I get this output and why it should print a newline?

Comment: Don't use stuff from your example side above. Thats allover bad practise what he explains there and makes code unreadable e.g. `<?$c%4?$q+=print$a:0;` . Write a new-line in a normal way. Don't use this wired stuff `~õ`.

Comment: Whatever if you want to reproduce, keep this in mind (from the webside): _Make sure to set your text editor to latin1 (ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252) instead of UTF8 otherwise you will save those inverted bytes as multi-bytes which will do the opposite of what we are trying to do here._

Comment: @Foobar Yes, usually I write well formatted readable code, but in this particular case the goal is to write the program with less possible bytes, so saving 1 or 2 bytes will help. I would never code like that in a production situation.